# Titanium barColor property for searchBar not working IOS7 with Titanium 3.1.2 SDK

Tags: ios7, titanium, searchbar

Titanium barColor property for searchBar not  working with IOS7. I have Titanium 3.1.2 SDK project without alloy.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Sdk 3.1.2 was not supposed to work with iOS 7.Try 3.2 for working with iOS7